# Web scraping with selenium and python - xpath with contains text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I will try to make it really short. I am trying to click on a product that came out of a search from a website. Basically there is a list of matching products, and I want to click on the first one which contains the product name I searched in its title.
I will post the link of the website so you can inspect its DOM structure: https://www.tonercartuccestampanti.it/#/dfclassic/query=CE285A&query_name=match_and
In this case, many contain my query string, and I would simply like to click on the first one.

Here is the snippet of code I wrote for this:

```
def click_on_first_matching_product(self):
        first_product = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 6).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, f"//a[@class='df-card__main']/div/div[@class=df-card__title] and contains(text(), '{self.product_code}')"))
        )[0]
        first_product.click()
```

The problem is that 6 seconds go by and it cant find an element that satisfies the xPath condition i wrote, but I cant figure out how to make it work.
I am trying to get a search result **a element** and check if the title it has down its structure contains the query string I searched.
Can I have some help and an explanation please? I am quite new to selenium and XPaths...

Can I please also have a link to a reliable selenium documentation? I am having some hard times trying to find a good one. Maybe one that also explains how to make conditions for xPaths please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider a couple of things. Your use-case would be either to click on the first search result or to click on the item with respect to the card title. In case of clicking on a definite [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) inducing *WebDriverWait* for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()`  will be **too expensive**.

---

To click on the item with respect to the card title you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using the text *CE285A Toner Compatibile Per Hp LaserJet P1102* directly:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tonercartuccestampanti.it/#/dfclassic/query=CE285A&query_name=match_and')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='CE285A Toner Compatibile Per Hp LaserJet P1102']"))).click()
  ```
- Using a variable for the text through `format()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tonercartuccestampanti.it/#/dfclassic/query=CE285A&query_name=match_and')
  text = "CE285A Toner Compatibile Per Hp LaserJet P1102"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='{}']".format(text)))).click()
  ```
- Using a variable for the text through `%s`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tonercartuccestampanti.it/#/dfclassic/query=CE285A&query_name=match_and')
  text = "CE285A Toner Compatibile Per Hp LaserJet P1102"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='%s']"% str(text)))).click()
  ```

---

To click on first search product you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tonercartuccestampanti.it/#/dfclassic/query=CE285A&query_name=match_and')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.df-card>a"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.tonercartuccestampanti.it/#/dfclassic/query=CE285A&query_name=match_and')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='df-card']/a"))).click()
  ```

---

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you I used the second approach you suggested me. I just changed it to have 'contains' and the name of my product in the title instead of hardcoding the whole title.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath seems incorrect.Try following xpath to click on product.

```
driver.get("https://www.tonercartuccestampanti.it/#/dfclassic/query=CE285A&query_name=match_and")
def click_on_first_matching_product(product_code):
    first_product = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='df-card__title' and contains(text(), '{}')]".format(product_code))))[0]
    first_product.click()
click_on_first_matching_product("CE285A")
```